# Guarantee visible signature in PDF doc

Tags: image-processing

I am looking into trying to guarantee visible signature in C#. Just looking for some ideas or a good point in the right direction.

In a pdf document, I have been able to guarantee the digital signature of the document.

However, I am having issues finding something that is able to actually read the pdf document and verify that there is indeed a visible signature within the document. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use Microsoft Office Document Imaging, I don't think that this is the right tool for the job.

EDIT: I need to actually read the image and verify that it is the correct signature.

Comment: Sounds like an open-ended imaging question. Your question does not appear to be related to DocuSign or the DocuSignAPI tag. Good luck.

Comment: what do you mean with visible signature? a hand written signature? a watermark? digital watermark?